# Calculating prices by javascript in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm using `laravel` and I want to sum two numbers and show it in my blade.

### Logic

1. I have hidden input field which is holding my product price
2. I have drop-down options which users can select
3. When users select any of the options my product price should sum to
   that option price and return the result as total to users.

### Codes

`<!--hidden field of product price-->`

```
<input type="hidden" id="harga" name="harga" value="{{$product->price}}">
```

`<!--div to show total price-->`

```
<div id="totalPriceInTotal"></div>
```

`<!--my options-->`

```
<select name="attr[]" class="form-control">
  <option value="">{{ __('Select') }}</option>
  @foreach($optioncollection as $suboption)
    <option value="{{$suboption->id}}">{{$suboption->title}} - {{ __('Rp') }} {{ number_format($suboption->price, 0) }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var optionprice = document.getElementById('harga').val();

      $.ajax({
        success:function(data) {
          // var optionprice = $(#attr).val();
          var shipingcost = parseFloat(data)+parseFloat(optionprice);
          var shipingcostnumber = shipingcost;
          var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
              maximumFractionDigits:0, 
              minimumFractionDigits:0
          });
          $('#totalPriceInTotal').append('<p>Cost: Rp '+nf.format(shipingcostnumber)+'</p>');
        }
      });
  });
</script>
```

> PS: I am aware that my JavaScript code is wrong, what I'd tried to do
>   here was to getting my hidden input value in my `totalPriceInTotal`
>   div which obviously was unsuccessful and then try to add my drop-down
>   values into it.

### Questions

1. What should I change to get my hidden input value in my
   `totalPriceInTotal` div when page loads?
2. How do I add my options value into it?

Note: for my options part i cannot add my options prices into `value=""` part because i need that value to be id for my cart so I added the price in options like `{{ number_format($suboption->price, 0) }}` probably i need help to remove texts around this price before i can actually sum it with my product price.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

So Ihad to add function in my controller in order to get my drop-down options prices and here is my final code `I commented my parts for better understanding`

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // if option is not selected shows product price
    $('#totalPriceInTotal').empty();
    var productprice = $('#harga').val();
    var shipingcost = parseFloat(productprice);
    var shipingcostnumber = shipingcost;
    var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
        maximumFractionDigits:0, 
        minimumFractionDigits:0
    });
    $('#totalPriceInTotal').append('Rp '+nf.format(shipingcostnumber)+'');

    // if option is selected will sum product price and option price
    $('select[name="attr[]"]').on('change', function() {
      var productprice = $('#harga').val();
      var optionprice = $(this).val();
      if(optionprice) {
        $.ajax({
          url: '{{ url('admin/getoptionprice') }}/'+encodeURI(optionprice),
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          success:function(data) {
            $('#totalPriceInTotal').empty();
            var shipingcost = parseFloat(data)+parseFloat(productprice);
            var shipingcostnumber = shipingcost;
            var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
                maximumFractionDigits:0, 
                minimumFractionDigits:0
            });
            $('#totalPriceInTotal').append('Rp '+nf.format(shipingcostnumber)+'');
          }
        });
      }else{
       // if user decided to back to default and not using any option price will back to normal
        $('#totalPriceInTotal').empty();
        var productprice = $('#harga').val();
        var shipingcost = parseFloat(productprice);
        var shipingcostnumber = shipingcost;
        var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
            maximumFractionDigits:0, 
            minimumFractionDigits:0
        });
        $('#totalPriceInTotal').append('Rp '+nf.format(shipingcostnumber)+'');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Hope this can help others.

Answer (score 1):

I advise giving the hidden field a data attribute, e.G

```
<input type="hidden" id="harga" name="harga" data-price="{{$product->price}}">
```

Then in JavaScript you can do this:

```
$('#harga').data('price');
```

You can do the same for the dropdown, although I do not fully comprehend what this does

> {{$suboption->id}}">{{$suboption->title}} - {{ __('Rp') }} {{ number_format($suboption->price, 0) }}

You can then take both values and add them to each other, and then append them to the "totalPriceInTotal" div (which is a terrible name imho ^^)

If appending does not work, just use

```
$('#totalPriceInTotal').val() = '<p>Cost: Rp ' + calculatedPrice + '</p>';
```

At this point I am not sure what EXACTLY does not work for you, so if you need more help, please let me know!